# 'Method Not Allowed: The method is not allowed for the requested URL.' when submitting text entry

Tags: python, html, flask

I am running flask python along with HTML, and the problem is simple:

It gives me error 405: Method Not Allowed: The method is not allowed for the requested URL. I have looked this up and people say to include methods=['GET', 'POST'] in the page route, but I already have this.

Python code:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    global count
    guess = request.form.get('guess')
    result, valid = guess_word(guess, word, words)
    print(result, valid)
    try:
            guesses[count-1][2] = 'p'
    except:
            guesses[count-1][2] = ''
    if count < 6:
        if valid:
            guesses[count][0] = guess
            guesses[count][1] = result
    session['guesses'] = guesses
    if valid:
        count += 1
    return render_template('index.html', guesses=session['guesses'])
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="container2">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Guess" class="text-input" name="guess">
    </form>
</div>
```

This worked before, and I changed (what I thought was) nothing, but it suddenly stopped working. It gives me the error when I submit the text entry.

Comment: Have you tried adding the methods to '/' aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form has no `action` attribute i.e. you have not explicitly said where your data should go to when you submit your form. In the absence of an `action` attribute, it will assume your home page which is `/` and from your routing, this does not support `POST`.

2 possible solutions

1. Add the `action` attribute to your form

```
<form action ="home" method ="post">
```

2. Keep your data as is and add support for POST to your route for `/` i.e. change your routing code to

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```